# Proving an exponential function dominates over an erratic fractional part

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, diophantine-approximation

Consider the function $3^x(1-2^{-\text{frac}(x\sqrt2)})$, where $\text{frac}()$ denotes the fractional part function. Now $\sqrt 2$ being irrational by kronecker, this is uniformly dense in $(0,1)$, which means that $\text{frac}(x\sqrt2)$ **can get very close to zero**.

**I want to prove that for sufficiently large positive integers $x$, this function is bigger than any specified lower bound.** To be very specific, for any positive real $L$, prove that there is a positive integer $N$, such that the function evaluated at any positive integer greater than $N$, gives a value bigger than $L$. Now the above thing causes an issue.
The above clearly seems to be true by Wolfram and it is intuitively clear this should be true,in a sense that even if the fractional part approaches zero, the exponential should dominate it and the function shouldn't experience a "sharp drop" over the positive integers.
It is fairly easy to prove that it is unbounded again by kronecker but i have no idea how to prove the above.

Comment: The very recent paper https://comptes-rendus.academie-sciences.fr/mathematique/item/10.5802/crmath.314.pdf could be very interesting to read

Comment: Yeah its interesting but are there any results for non algebraic irrationals say frac(xlog(3+2*sqrt(2)),where x is a positive integer.Any lower bound in some good enough computable function of x,will do the job.Like the person who answered below found a lower bound for sqrt(2) case but is there something for this one.Anything weak should also work in my opinion as the claim should be true defintiely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a lower bound for the approximation of $\sqrt2$ by fractions.

---

**Lemma**. Suppose $x,y$ are positive integers. Then $$\left|\sqrt 2x-y\right|>\frac1{5x}$$
**Proof**. There are two cases.

- $y>3x$.
  Then $$\sqrt 2x-y<\sqrt2x-3x<-x\le-1$$
  So, $|\sqrt2x-y|>1>\frac1{5x}$.
- $y\le 3x$.
  $$|\sqrt 2x-y| |\sqrt 2x+y|=|2x^2-y^2|\ge1,$$ where the last inequality holds because $2x^2-y^2$ is a nonzero integer.
  So, $$|\sqrt 2x-y| \ge\frac1{|\sqrt 2x+y|}>\frac1{5x}$$

---

Since $y$ is arbitrary, the lemma implies $\text{frac}(x\sqrt2)>\frac1{5x}$ for any positive integer $x$.

$$\begin{aligned}
3^x(1-2^{-\text{frac}(x\sqrt2)})
&\ge3^x(1-2^{-\frac1{5x}})\\
&=3^x(1-e^{-\frac{\ln 2}{5x}})\\
&>3^x(1-(1+\frac12(-\frac{\ln 2}{5x}))\\
&=\frac{\ln2}{10}\frac{3^x}{x}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
which goes to $\infty$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$.

The last inequality above uses the following inequality: $e^z<1+\frac z2$ when $z\in(-\frac12,0)$.

Comment: Can u also tell how to prove the same thing  if frac(x*sqrt(2)) is replaced by frac(x*log(3+2*sqrt(2)).The problem I wanted to solve  requires the latter.I just posted the former for convience ,thinking the same method might carry on for the other case,but it does not since we can't get a similar lower bound in the other case for the fractional part.

Comment: The new case is different enough that you may want to ask a new question. It seems related to [Baker's theorem](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem).